# While loop in Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, console

I want to make a while...loop statement in my Shell script like:

```
while [ $line < $line_number ]; do
    echo $line
done
```

But there is an error. I think it is because I wrote it in `bash` code. But I need to do it in `sh` mode. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: "But there is an error." What error? Do you mean an error message, or just that something doesn't work as you intended? What happens exactly? And how are you running your script? I recommend *editing your question* to include all this information.

Comment: OK, I will edit my question. Yes, I have an error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use, either

```
while [ $line -lt $line_number ]; do
    echo $line
done
```

or

```
while [[ $line < $line_number ]]; do
    echo $line
done
```

**Disscussion**<sup>[[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542854/2026294)</sup>

Single `[]` are posix shell compliant condition tests.

Double `[[]]` are an extension to the standard `[]` and are supported by bash and other shells (e.g. zsh, ksh). They support extra operations (as well as the standard posix operations). For example: `||` instead of `-o` and regex matching with `=~`. A fuller list of differences can be found in the [bash manual section on conditional constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Use `[]` whenever you want your script to be portable across shells. Use `[[]]` if you want conditional expressions not supported by `[]` and don't need to be portable.

Comment: Yes, it worked with `-le`. Thanks!

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov plz see the edit, it will be `-lt` which is equivalent to `<`, `-le` means `<=`